How do I fix a toilet that randomly gets clogged without much getting put down?
The majority of the time the toilet gets clogged with any small thing like just taking a #1, and even a small #2 and it's clogged.
It'll immediately get plunged, sometimes it works for it to be flushed fully with no problems for a few days then out of nowhere it's clogged again and it'll get stubborn and won't unclog for the life of it, and it'll stay like that, clogged for a few days then again its unclogged for a flush or 2. Same darn cycle day in and day out.
I've tried Drano, dish soap and hot water sometimes it helps but like I said it only helps for a couple of flushes and such. I've also used a snake a few times to no avail.
I have removed the toilet from the floor. The hole in the floor after the toilet is removed seems to be working fine from what I can see, because I've put dish soap and hot water down the drain and it goes down with no issues whatsoever.
I suspect it's some kind of toy that's wedged in the toilet really good.
How do I get the object out of the toilet? I rent this home.

A plumbing snake will locate the problem area.  There a few turns/bends(the P-trap like under a sink) between the bowl and the bottom so reaching in is difficult.

I edited this down some. Entertaining to read for English speakers perhaps, but this is an international site and we need to bring it up for those who don't understand the slang. Expletives are also out of bounds.

Being that this is a rental, you may not be allowed to remove the toilet and will get in trouble if the landlord finds out. Replacing the toilet will require a new wax seal on the bottom, and following proper procedure: don't remount the toilet with the old wax seal. Regarding the possible obstruction, you may just have to reach in for it, or snake it from underneath to push the object out into the bowl.

stating this is a rental home does not mean poster is the renter.

if you suspect the clog is in the toilet, with toilet outside you set it up on something to allow you to observe the bottom end when flushing.  simply pour a 5 gal bucket worth of water into bowl.  if it doesn't blow though and out the bottom then u know, if you have good garden hose pressure just blast into the toilet from the bottom

@ron   There could be an object in the toilet tubes/pipes that lets liquid through okay, but grabs toilet paper/more solid stuff and clogs up.  If OP plunges the toilet first, could pour water all day and say it was fine.

@ron The original post pre-edit says OP "told the landlord". Missed that part when editing out the extras. Nuance fixed.

In my case, the toilet appears to be fine, and the problem is an occasional partial blockage in the drain pipes. A long snake would probably be able to solve that. Meanwhile, I have just been using a plunger once a year when the problem occurs, and that has been sufficient to shake free whatever is happening.

For a few £/€/$ you can get a USB endoscope, basically a waterproof webcam with built-in lights on a  long cable.  That will let you see what's blocking the pipe, and help you guide a hook if that's what you need to get the blockage out

Draino will not clean anything out of a toilet, it wreaks havoc on the pipes, and it's horrible for the environment. It should really never be used. Anything that clears the toilet will usually not clog the drain, so you have probably missed the clog in the toilet.

Plunging - most people don't realize the point of plunging is to pull things out, not shove them down. Take care to get a gentle seal around the toilet drain, then depress slowly, then with negative pressure, give a hard YANK to suck things forward much as you can.

Toilet augur. A toilet augur is a snake with a tube and a rubberized 90 that can go into the toilet bowl without scratching it - great for a rental. I've undone most toilet clogs with this. For things like a diaper or a wad of paper towels, try to feed the hook in until you feel the clog, give it one sharp turn to "hook" the mass, and continue spinning and hooking as you go to continually bind the object as you pull it out.

Remove the toilet. This is the most challenging to do for a home gamer. Toilets are very hard to install. Shut off water, flush as much out as will go, dump a bucket of water to flush out a remaining level, suck out remaining water with a shop vac. Remove closet flange nuts. Carefully lift toilet up, set it on it's side (lay down towels for this to prevent chipping porcelain) run a sturdy object like a snake up the toilet to dislodge anything stuck in the bend. I retrieved a toy rubber donut this way. Scrape off old wax ring, lay a new wax ring according to instructions, very carefully lift and set toilet down completely upright.



toilets are not very hard to install

@ron  It is installing them right that can be difficult for a first timer.  Imagine a few first timers just turned the bolts one turn too tight or lower the toilet down at an angle onto the wax ring.

@ron if my answer offers one good thing to OP, it's to add a new wax ring since they already removed the toilet once.
